# docker exited with code 126 (0x7E) in Asp.Net Core in Windows 10

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I have just downloaded Asp.Net core in my Windows 10 and now created a Asp.Net Core Web API. Whenever I run my application, I am getting an error as ""docker" exited with code 126 (0x7E)."

[image]

> I am using Docker community edition, Version 17.06.0-ce-win19 (12801) Channel: stable c98c1c2

And I am pretty much sure that my Docker is up and running.

[image]

It would be great if you can put some light on this.

**Update:**

Forgot to mention that I was getting this error message as well "unable to start debugging, unable to establish a connection to VSDBG"

Comment: 126 = ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND, so you miss a DLL/dependency

Comment: @magicandre1981 Can you please elaborate a bit? And do we need to enable Hyper-V in our system to use Docker?

Comment: I have no idea, I never used docker. I only looked what the error code means

Answer (score 0):

Try running docker as "Run As Admin" and see?

For debugging with Visual Studio, try with latest Visual Studio 2017 Update 3 Preview. This version has added support for latest Docker Images.